# Check if BT is BST with T extend Comparable<T> java

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

Check is BT is BST is simple to but I'm struggling with the algorithm while using Comparable class.

First of all, I have the given insert method for BT:

```
public void insert(T item){
    //initialize new BT and sets left, right, parent and data to null
    BinaryTree<T> newNode = new BinaryTree<T>();
    newNode.setData(item);

    if (size==0){
        tree = newNode;
        size++;
        return;
    }

    BinaryTree<T> t = tree;
    boolean done = false;

    while (!done){
        int c = item.compareTo(t.getData());
        if (c==0){
            System.out.println("Duplicate key. Can't insert");
            return;
        }
        //need to go left
        else if (c<0){
            //place to insert found
            if (t.getLeft()==null){
                t.setLeft(newNode);
                newNode.setParent(t);
                size++;
                done = true;
            }
            else
                //otherwise go left one branch
                t = t.getLeft();
        }
        //c>0; need to go right
        else{
            //place to insert found
            if (t.getRight()==null){
                t.setRight(newNode);
                newNode.setParent(t);
                size++;
                done=true;
            }
            else
                t = t.getRight();
        }
    }
}
```

I insert both  4 2 5 1 3 into BT, and 1 2 3 4 into BT
the tree looks like:

```
    4
   / \
  2   5
 / \
1   3


 1
  \
   2
    \
     3
      \
       4
```

and the result still return true.

For the validation method for BST:

```
public static<T extends Comparable<T>> boolean isBinarySearchTree(BinaryTree<T> t){

    if(t ==null){
        return true;
    }
    if(t.getLeft()!=null && t.getLeft().getData().compareTo(t.getData())>0){
        return false;
    }
    if(t.getRight() !=null && t.getRight().getData().compareTo(t.getData())<0){
        return false;
    }
    return isBinarySearchTree(t.getLeft()) && isBinarySearchTree(t.getRight());
}
```

I want to using T extend comparable <> ,  and inputting  BinaryTree t into the method into the method.
However I'm confused that why the method still determines that the second BT is also BST.

Comment: Your BinaryTree class is already creating binary search trees. The second example is also a BST. Unless you want to test balanced BSTs?

Comment: Yes, i think I didn't clarify that  I want to test balanced BST. It my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about adding an extra height method:

```
int height(BinaryTree bt) {
    if (bt == null) {
       return 0;
    }
    return 1 + Math.max(height(bt.getLeft()), height());
}
```

And then adding an extra if statement in your isBinarySearchTree check:

```
if (height(t.getRight()) != height(t.getLeft())) {
    return false;
}
```

This is adding O(log n) to the complexity though as it's possibly running through the height of the tree on every level.